# python choose one object from array

Tags: python, arrays, find, highlighting

I have a script that is returning the start/end locations of strings in a gtk textview object.
I feel like I am doing the same thing over and over.
the first search function returns the start,end of each match location. the second I was hoping would search and highlight each object in the textview given by the array.
the searchn() I noticed that I can change the array selection and choose the 2nd to last or what ever I choose.

Is there a way to choose one at a time each object that in an array per click so it will highlight the one object in order in the array.

so If I have four words

work
work
work 
work

then I can highlight the first one then I click again and it will re-run the function and highlight the 2nd then 3rd and when it is all complete I can just make it go back to the beginning.I was thinking that someting like.
for range in len(z):
  do this 
but no matter what I do it in a for loop it selects the last one steps on the last. I hope this makes sense.

```
def search(x):
search_required = False
sbuffer.remove_tag_by_name('found', sbuffer.get_start_iter(), sbuffer.get_end_iter())
    find_text = findentry.get_text()
    if find_text:
  text = sbuffer.get_text(sbuffer.get_start_iter(),sbuffer.get_end_iter()).decode('utf8')
      search_matches = [(match.start(), match.end()) for match in re.finditer(re.escape(find_text), text, re.IGNORECASE)]
      if len(search_matches) < 1000:
    for start,end in search_matches:
      iter1 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(start)
      iter2 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(end)
      sbuffer.select_range(iter1, iter2)
      sbuffer.apply_tag_by_name('found', iter1, iter2)
    textview.scroll_to_mark(sbuffer.get_mark('insert'), 0.25)
    print search_matches
    return search_matches
else:
  search_matches = [ ]    



  def searchn(x):
search(x)
z=search(x)
#def SN(z)
print len(z)
z=z[:1]# need to have this do to 2nd,3rd,4th,5th ect till there are no more matches.
for a,l in z:
  print a,"start of this match"
  print l, "end of this match"
  iter1 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(a)
  iter2 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(l)
  sbuffer.select_range(iter1,iter2)
  print z
return z
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use regex to find the instances of the word you are looking for and then once you have all the indexes do your looping.

Example:

```
import re
sentence = "You are my favorite. Are you my friend? Are you an elephant?"
items = []
for item in re.finditer("[Aa]re", sentence, ):
    items.append(item.start())
```

This should give you the locations that the words are at. Once you have those, you should be able to quickly and easily step through those locations any way you like.

Comment: I have the locations of all the words and yes I am using re for it as well. perhaps I've missed something but is there a way to do something  items[:1] then the next time I run the function it will be items[:2] so that I can go through the array and highlight them? BTW Thank you for the quick reply mate!:)

Comment: How about you put the list creation into a function, which you will use when you want to find all the words. Then as you highlight the words, just remove the first item in the list each time you iterate through it?

Comment: sounds like a good Idea, I was thinking about this selecting work[:1] list.remove work[:1].I'll see if it works. if you know of a good way to do this please let me know ;) . Thanks Trying it now.

Comment: <br />here is what I have <br />def searchn(x):
 #search(x)
 z=search(x)
 #print len(z)
 print z , "First"
 z=z[:1] # need to have this do to 2,3,4,5 ect till there are no more matches.
 if findentry.get_text() != " ":
   for a,l in z[:1]:
     #print a,l
     iter1 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(a)
     iter2 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(l)
     sbuffer.select_range(iter1,iter2)
 del z [:1]

Answer (score 0):

you know the idea did come to me in a dream a couple of nights ago. I just kept messing it up...:P
here is is working. and Thank you JazzyWhite!
Python search function forward and backward. I hope it helps anyone that would want to make something like this. For anyone else looking Base is my main class and sbuffer is textview.get_buffer() and yes I am using gtk.

```
  searchmatchp=None
  searchmatchf=None
  def search(x):
sbuffer.remove_tag_by_name('found', sbuffer.get_start_iter(), sbuffer.get_end_iter())
    find_text = findentry.get_text()
    if find_text:
  text = sbuffer.get_text(sbuffer.get_start_iter(),sbuffer.get_end_iter()).decode('utf8')
      search_matches = [(match.start(), match.end()) for match in re.finditer(re.escape(find_text), text, re.IGNORECASE)]
      if len(search_matches) < 1000:
    for start,end in search_matches:
      iter1 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(start)
      iter2 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(end)
      sbuffer.select_range(iter1, iter2)
      sbuffer.apply_tag_by_name('found', iter1, iter2)
    textview.scroll_to_mark(sbuffer.get_mark('insert'), 0.25)
    Base.searchmatchp=search_matches
    Base.searchmatchf=search_matches
    #return search_matches
else:
  search_matches = [ ]    



  def searchn(self):
print Base.searchmatchf
for a,l in Base.searchmatchf[:1]:
  iter1 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(a)
  iter2 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(l)
  sbuffer.select_range(iter1,iter2)
  textview.scroll_to_mark(sbuffer.get_mark('insert'), 0.25)
del Base.searchmatchf[:1]  
if Base.searchmatchf ==[]:
  search(self)




  def searchp(self):
print Base.searchmatchp
del Base.searchmatchp[-1:] 
print Base.searchmatchp[-1:]
for a,l in Base.searchmatchp[-2:]:
  iter1 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(a)
  iter2 = sbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(l)
  sbuffer.select_range(iter1,iter2)
  textview.scroll_to_mark(sbuffer.get_mark('insert'), 0.25)
if Base.searchmatchp ==[]:
  search(self)
```